# show admob without refresh on multiple activities

Tags: android, admob

I have a AdMob layout which I want to display on all activities. I also have a function in my `BaseActivity` which loads the ad but on every activity change it takes a few seconds to load the ad. Is there any way to display the the ad without a delay?

function:

```
 public static void SetAD(AdView adView){
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }
```

usage

```
RelativeLayout llroot = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rladmob);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.admob, null);
        BaseActivity.SetAD((AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.adView));
        llrot.addView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to use Fragments and have the view/functionality of your different Activities contained with separate Fragment. And the load the Fragment instead of switching Activities.

That way you only have a single AdView.

Using Fragments like this is also a much cleaner design.